# Can I have an input type=text in the same form with an input type=file in a jsp page?

Tags: java, forms, jsp

I have a form in my jsp page where there is an input for text and an input for file.

```
<form action="servlet/FileUploadHandler" method="post" class="post" id="profilepost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="createPost">Photo</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" id="inputcomment" placeholder="URL...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Upload photo</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="exampleInputFile">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

The servlet I use is the following:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\ismgroup9\\fileUpload";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        try {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
                    request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
                }
            }

           request.setAttribute("message", "File Uploaded Successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        }

    }else{
        request.setAttribute("message", "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/uploadfileController.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

}

But this is only for the photo. What can I do so as to have both text and photo? I want to insert them in the same table in my mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, maybe it will help you solve your problem.

```
for(FileItem item : multiparts){
    if(!item.isFormField()){
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
        request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
    }else{
        // here get value of other parameter which is not file type
        System.out.println(item.getFieldName()+" = "+item.getString());
    }
}
```